# Finding an area enclosed by 4 curves

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, regions

Question is given: Consider the functions $f(x)=x \cos(x)$, $g(x)=-x^3+6$, $h(x)=-10x-50$, $k(x)=sin(x^2/3)+13$.

1. Plot the graphs of the four functions for x in the interval [-8,5].  You should see a region R enclosed by the graphs.  Choose a scale for the y axis so that the region is clearly visible.  Find the four intersection points that define the corners of the region, and draw a black dot at each point. 
   **Note:** The region that must be calculated is approx between when x=-6, x=2, x=-1 and y=12, we're not interested in the region where g(x) and h(x) intersect at (5,-100)
2. Find the area of R given in numerical

My approach:

```
f = x*Cos[x]
g = -x^3 + 6
h = -10*x - 50
k = Sin[x^2/3] + 13

fCurves = Plot[{f, g, h, k}, {x, -8, 5}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

```
ActReg = Curves = Plot[{f, g, h, k}, {x, -8, 2.5},
  PlotLegends   ->"Expressions"]
```

[image]

```
Area = RegionPlot[y > f && y < g && y > h && y < k, {x, -8, 3}, {y, -50, 
50}, PlotPoints -> 200, FrameLabel -> {x, y}]

fg = x /. NSolve[f == g, x, Reals];
fh = x /. NSolve[f == h, x, Reals];
kg = x /. NSolve[k == g, x, Reals];
kh = x /. NSolve[k == h, x, Reals];
Column[{fg, fh, kg, kh}]
```

My problem was the intersection points. Since the equations are working with respect to x, how do you get the y coordinates for each intersected point?

I tried `NSolve` but only gave me x coordinates, which looks correct in terms of the values for x but is missing the y coordinates.

Comment: This site is not for us to do your homework problems.

Comment: "Since the equations are working with respect to x, how do you get the y coordinates for each intersected point".  Ah. You found `x` satisfying `f[x]==g[x]` , the "y" value is just `f[x]` no?

Comment: Yes I believe so

Comment: @DavidG.Stork OP has put some effort though.

Comment: @mastud89 if so and if you know you can do `x /. NSolve` then you can also do `{x, f} /. NSolve`

Comment: Very helpful, thank you!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, we define the functions as such and solve with replacement rules to find the corner points for the region of interest:

```
f = Function[ x, x Cos[x] ];
g = Function[ x, -x^3 + 6 ];
h = Function[ x, -10 x - 50];
k = Function[ x, Sin[x^2/3] + 13];

p1 = {x, h[x]} /. First @NSolve[ f[x] == h[x], x, Reals];
p2 = {x, g[x]} /. First@NSolve[ g[x] == k[x], x, Reals];
p3 = {x, k[x]} /. First@NSolve[ k[x] == h[x], x, Reals];
p4 = {x, f[x]} /. First@NSolve[ f[x] == g[x], x, Reals];

{p1, p2, p3, p4} // Grid[#, Alignment -> Decimal] &
```

[image: Points]

```
plot = Plot[
  Evaluate@Through[{f, g, h, k}@x], {x, -8, 5},
  PlotRange -> {{-8, 5}, {-20, 20}},
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point@{p1, p2, p3, p4}},
  PlotLabels -> Automatic
]
```

[image: Corners]

Now we can define the relevant regions (e.g. halfplanes) with regard to the functions and define their intersection as the region of interest:

```
rf = ImplicitRegion[ y >= f[x], {x, y}];
rg = ImplicitRegion[ y <= g[x], {x, y}];
rh = ImplicitRegion[ y >= h[x], {x, y}];
rk = ImplicitRegion[ y <= k[x], {x, y}];

intersection = RegionIntersection @@ {rf, rg, rh, rk};
```

The `intersection` is a region which can immediately be displayed using [`Region`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Region.html):

```
Region[intersection, PlotRange -> {{-8, 5}, {-5, 20}}]
```

[image: Region of Interest]

Its area can be found using [`Area`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Area.html):

```
Area @ intersection // N
```

> 65.6591

Comment: kglr has given a wonderfully concise and compact solution (+1, of course). Here I wanted to be more explicit and also demonstrate the use of regions to reach an answer.

Answer (score 11):

```
Show[RegionPlot[Max[f, h] <= y <= Min[g, k], {x, -8, 5}, {y, -5, 15}, PlotPoints -> 100], 
 Plot[{f, g, h, k}, {x, -8, 5}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]]
```

[image]

```
NIntegrate[Boole[Max[f, h] <= y <= Min[g, k]], {x, -8, 5}, {y, -30, 30}]
```

> 65.68095